# Shifting -5 V to +5 V signal to 0 to +5 V for ADC

Tags: digital-logic, adc

I want to convert the  output voltage of an ECG (-5 to +5) to 0 - +5 volt for ADC.
Should i use Op amp ?
What is my problem in this picture?
I simulated it in Proteus ... but when input voltage is higher than 4 V or lower than -4 V Vout gives an unexpected value.
[image]

Below is another simulink that have same problem ...
[image]

My idea to make this level of voltage is (Vin +10)/2 that give the range 0-5 V.

Comment: Please use proper capitalisation and punctuation as required in standard English for this site. Question edited.

Comment: The 741 opamp can not swing to negative rail. Find a better opamp.

Comment: look here https://www.olimex.com/Products/Duino/Shields/SHIELD-EKG-EMG/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 741 can't accept an input that's too close to the negative rail. The data sheet says the input range is +/- 13V when the power supply is +/- 15V.  Not sure about when the negative power supply is 0V but I doubt it will work the way you expect with a 0V input. Similar story on the output side. That would explain the strange numbers you're getting below -4V input. Don't know what's going on with the +4V input since there would seem to be plenty of headroom with your +12V supply. Does the simulation work if you power the 741 with +/- 15V? It looks basically correct if you assume that the op amp is ideal.